# Android Studio 3.1 database class code edit slow

Tags: android, android-studio

After I've updated to the latest stable version of Android Studio (3.1), the class where I handle my database became suddenly very slow when I work on it. 
For example when I paste a text in the class.
The problem arose only in the java class that handles the database, all other classes are ok.

I know that they added a new feature in Android Studio 3.1 regarding the SQL completion.
There is a way to disable it? It could be the cause of the problem.

There could be any other problem?
I've already tried to clean the project.